# Sqlite for Cordova Windows 10 UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, winjs, windows-10-universal

I'm working cordova app for Windows 10 UWP(WinJS)  application which should have sqlite option for storing data. I search SQLite for WinJS cordova sample but I couldn't find any.

could you please suggest best API for implementing SQLite for WinJS windows UWP app?

Answer (score 3):

Cordova sqlite storage plugin does support Win10 apps generated from Cordova.

Here is the project: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage
And here is a sample : https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext

I think with this you have everything you need ! :)

Comment: Im getting exception while compiling.